# page refresh countdown timer does not continue using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

var seconds=3600;
function secondPassed() {

   var minutes = Math.round((seconds-30)/60);
    console.log(minutes);
    var hours=Math.round((minutes)/60);

   var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
   if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
       remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =hours + ":"+ minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds;
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time Out";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }

}
var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed ,1000);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="countdown"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

MY Question : page refresh and countdown timer does not continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using javascript cookies only but you need to use two file
first file contains total time you need for countdown i.e in your code is 3600 seconds

let us take first file index.html write code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Countdown timer</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var seconds = 3600;
  document.cookie = "timer=" + seconds;
  window.location.href = "time.html";
 </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Next second file let us take time.html add below code

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>


function getCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
//alert(document.cookie);
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
var c = ca[i];
while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) != -1) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
} 


// var seconds=7200;
// document.cookie = "timer=" + seconds;
function secondPassed() {

  seconds = parseInt(getCookie('timer'));
  console.log(seconds);
   var minutes = parseInt(seconds / 60, 10);
    console.log(minutes);

   var  remainingSeconds = parseInt(seconds % 60, 10);

   if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
       remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds;  
    }

    document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML =  minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + ' minutes remaning';
    if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        document.getElementById('countdown').innerHTML = "Time Out";
    } else {
        seconds--;
    }
    document.cookie = "timer=" + (seconds);

}
var myVar = setInterval(secondPassed ,1000);

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p id="countdown"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : whenever you want to run countdown timer just run time.html, even if you refresh also, time remains same

Note : if you want to refresh page or want to add when time up add your activity in

```js
if (seconds == 0) {
        clearInterval(myVar);
        // add activity
    }
```

Comment: @ SHAKEEL MOHAMMAD when page refresh but countdown doest not work

Comment: means second can noot dcrement

Comment: means when page refreshed, timer should stop ??

Comment: @ SHAKEEL MOHAMMAD page refresh but countdown timer does not work

Comment: page refresh ,timer stop ,why?

Comment: what exactly u need ?

Comment: 1. when you do page refresh, timer should continue 2. when you do page refresh, timer should stop ??

Comment: when you do page refresh, timer should continue

Comment: @ SHAKEEL MOHAMMAD    
1. when you do page refresh, timer should continue

Comment: That's what i have given code, initially run index.html file, it will create cookie, then it will automatically redirect to time.html, then onward just run time.html, then u can able to see continuing of timer